# Issue with django-db-geventpool

Tags: python, django, celery, gevent

In order to fix an issue related to the high number of database connections opened (OperationalError('FATAL: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections\n',) ) I have tried to use https://github.com/jneight/django-db-geventpool and updated the DATABASE settings , But it didn't work with celery and all queues then were stuck.

I don't know if it's related to this section https://github.com/jneight/django-db-geventpool#using-django-16-orm-when-not-serving-requests but I don't know how to apply it.

I am using:

```
 - Django 1.9.2
 - celery 3.1.19
 - gevent 1.1b1
```

I have the following celery file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Celery configuration file
"""
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from __future__ import absolute_import

import os


def post_fork():
    """ post_fork
    # if its a gevent queue (all queues except scrapy-* queues)
    """
    from gevent import monkey
    monkey.patch_all()
    from psycogreen.gevent import patch_psycopg
    patch_psycopg()


# post_fork must run before anyother imports
if os.environ.get('GEVENT', None):
    post_fork()

from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings

from etc.celerybase.routers import GlobalRouter

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings.sites.app')

app = Celery('pb', broker=getattr(settings, 'BROKER_URL', 'redis://'))

app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings')

# Optional configuration, see the application user guide.
app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE='low',
    CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE='low',
    CELERY_DEFAULT_ROUTING_KEY='low',
    CELERY_CREATE_MISSING_QUEUES=True,
    CELERY_ROUTES=(
        GlobalRouter(),
    ),
)
```

Supervisor file:

```
[program:celery_medium]
command=newrelic-admin run-program celery -A miap worker -E -Q low -P gevent -c 300 --loglevel=ERROR
directory=/var/lib/app
environment=NEW_RELIC_CONFIG_FILE="/var/lib/app/pb/newrelic
/SETTINGS_FILE/worker-medium.ini",DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="setting.sites.app",GEVENT="True"
```